# Permission denied to access property 'CKEDITOR'

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckfinder

I have integrated CKEditor and CKFinder in my sites. All worked well. But now on one of my sites there is a problem. Firebug shows:

```
Error: Permission denied to access property 'CKEDITOR'
```

I use the next code for integration:

```
CKFinder.setupCKEditor( null, 'ckfinder/' );
$( 'textarea.tarea_ckeditor' ).ckeditor();
```

What can be the problem here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Follow the steps bellow:

- Check the URL from the browser (maybe you are on the dev website) :D
- Check, if the files and your page is on the same domain (they should be).
- Do you make any redirects on the server (append www or even on another domain)?